# Replace multiple hex colors in string

Tags: php, regex

Im having problem with changing multiple HEX colors into span. Current code just change one color. Any idea how to make it work for multiple colors ?

```
function convertHexToSpan($name)
{
  $name = preg_replace('/\*#([a-f\d]{6})(.*)\*[a-f\d]+/', "<span style='color:$1'>$2</span>", $name);
  return $name;
}


$text = "#ff6600Hello #ff0000world";
$newText = convertHexToSpan($text);
OUTPUT SHOULD BE "<span style='color:#ff600'>Hello</span><span style='color:#ff0000'>world</span>
```

Comment: @ialarmedalien Edited

Comment: Your regular expression doesn't match your input, so you're not getting any replacements at present.

Comment: why are you looking for a * at the start of the hex color and before the word? '\\*' tells the regex to look for a literal *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating your Regular Expression will get you most of the way there, but we have to make some assumptions that differ slightly from your original question.

If you use the following as the expression:

```
/(#[a-f\d]{6})([^ ]+)/
```

preg_replace does the repetition searching for you as regex isn't really for iterating, so I removed the second hex search. This finds the 6 hex digits as a first group, then the next group is any character that is not a space.

Note: I am assuming that you are trying to break on word boundaries, but will need to modify if that is not the case. I am also assuming you want to preserve the space between the words after conversion, but your example shows no space.

To remove the space between words, you would just need to modify the regex to match the spaces (and then they will get removed), which would be as follows:

```
/(#[a-f\d]{6})([^ ]+)( )+/
```

Comment: Awesome dude! Could you write me same thing but without space between words ? I'm really bad at expressions. @i-man

Comment: Updated the answer to remove the space between words, basically, you just add a third group to catch spaces and then it will get replaced.